# python sort strings with digits in the beginning

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list like this

```
list = [Tree, Plant, Bird, 7animal, Beta, 4qwerty]
```

when I use sorted it gives me output like

```
sorted(list) = [Beta, Bird, Plant, Tree, 4qwerty, 7animal]
```

But I want output some thing like this

```
[Beta, Bird, 4qwerty, 7animal, Plant, Tree]
```

Since I want to consider `4=d` and `7=g`.
Ex: I want to consider `{1=a, 2=b, 3=c, 4=d,....26=z}`
How to achieve this ?

```
 def sort_list(list):
    return sorted(list)
```

Comment: So what if there's a string like `xy123`? Would that be `xyabc` or `xylc` or `xyaw` or what?

Comment: Write a function that normalized a string (`4` → `d`…) and give it as the argument `key` to the `sorted()` function.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `['4qwerty', '7animal', 'Beta', 'Bird', 'Plant', 'Tree']`?

Comment: I want to sort based on only first character. xy123 can remain as xy123. If the first character starts with number then I need to sort accordingly as explained above.

Comment: You said you want to consider `26=z`? 26 isn't a single character?

Comment: @Aran-Fey Good point. What would `112abc` be? `aababc`, `kbabc`, or `alabc`?

Comment: Updated the answer @reka, I was only taking the first letter in sorted, so it was only sorting based on that. Works fine now

Comment: @reka did any of the answer posted below helped? if it did you may accept it! cheers

Answer (score 1):

I think, you could replace that `digit` with a `mapping` like,

```
import re
import string

mapping = {str(idx): x for idx, x in enumerate(string.ascii_uppercase, 1)}
def key_func(val):
    match = re.search(r'^\d+', val)
    if match:
        digit = match.group()
        val = val.replace(digit, mapping[digit])
    return val

stuff = ['Tree', 'Plant', 'Bird', '7animal', 'Beta', '4qwerty']
x = sorted(stuff, key=key_func)
print(x)

['Beta', 'Bird', '4qwerty', '7animal', 'Plant', 'Tree']
```

Answer (score 0):

Incoming a ***Old-Schooler***:

**Explanation**:

Fucntion `NormalizeStrings()` to get respect value of the digit starting strings from the dictionary and append accordingly.

Function `replaceString()` to replace the values from the `dict_`

Function `DeNormalizeStrings()` to do opposite of `NormalizeStrings()`

Function `DereplaceString()` to to do opposite of `replaceString()`

```
alist = ['Tree', 'Plant', 'Bird', '7animal', 'Beta', '4qwerty']
alist2 = []

dict_ = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd', 5: 'e', 6: 'f', 7: 'g', 8: 'h', 9: 'i',
         10: 'j', 11: 'k', 12: 'l', 13: 'm', 14: 'n', 15: 'o', 16: 'p', 17: 'q', 18: 'r',
         19: 's', 20: 't', 21: 'u', 22: 'v', 23: 'w', 24: 'x', 25: 'y', 26: 'z'}

def replaceString(s):
    return s[0].replace(s[0],dict_[int(s[0])])

def NormalizeStrings(alist):
    for s in alist:
        if s[0].isdigit():
            s = replaceString(s) + s[1:]
            alist2.append(s)
        else:
            alist2.append(s)

def DeReplaceString(s):
    for name in dict_:
        if dict_[name] == s[0]:
           return s[0].replace(s[0], str(name))

def DeNormalizeStrings(alist):
    alist2.clear()
    for s in alist:
        if s[0].islower():
            s = DeReplaceString(s) + s[1:]
            alist2.append(s)
        else:
            alist2.append(s)

NormalizeStrings(alist)
print(alist2)
print(sorted(alist2, key=lambda s: s.lower()))
DeNormalizeStrings(sorted(alist2, key=lambda s: s.lower()))
print(alist2)
```

OUTPUT:

```
['Tree', 'Plant', 'Bird', 'ganimal', 'Beta', 'dqwerty']
['Beta', 'Bird', 'dqwerty', 'ganimal', 'Plant', 'Tree']
['Beta', 'Bird', '4qwerty', '7animal', 'Plant', 'Tree']
```